# Recommendations for a good PHP HTTP class

Tags: php, http

For previous projects I have used

```
/**
 * HTTP Class
 *
 * This is a wrapper HTTP class that uses either cURL or fsockopen to
 * harvest resources from web. This can be used with scripts that need
 * a way to communicate with various APIs who support REST.
 *
 * @author      Md Emran Hasan <phpfour@gmail.com>
 * @package     HTTP Library
 * @copyright   2007-2008 Md Emran Hasan
 * @link        http://www.phpfour.com/lib/http
 * @since       Version 0.1
 */
```

This works very well but does not appear to have been updated in quite some time (indeed, the link above does not even work now...).

My latest project is going to make heavy use of http methods (accessing cross domain and internal APIs) so I need to make sure I am using as efficient an http class/library as possible.

What do you use for this functionality?

Comment: What do you need to do?  Why do you need to use a class (there may be a need, but to figure out what to recommend, we need to know the requirements)...

Comment: If you aim for *efficient*, then PHPs new built-in [HttpRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) is it.

Comment: Has the HTTP protocol changed in the past 2 years to justify wanting an updated class?

Comment: @mario: it's not built-in.  It's a PECL extension.  While that's great if you have access to the server itself (to install PECL extensions), most don't.  Unless someone builds an open-source PHP implementation to be used as a fallback when it's not installed...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Already working on it.

Comment: @mario: Excellent. Glad to hear it!

Comment: @ircmaxell: Yes, I shouldn't really have specified 'an http class'. I wasn't aware of the PECL extension. These are exactly the sort of recommendations I am looking for.

Comment: @yc: Good point. However, if there is a faster or more secure or more robust way that has been developed in this period I should aim towards that.

Comment: I am the author of the class mentioned in the question. I myself use the PECL's HttpRequest library for any serious use, suggested below by Gordon and above in comments by mario. If you are not able to install pecl extensions, then you can try Guzzle (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP has a [native HTTP class in PECL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php):

> The HTTP extension eases handling of HTTP URLs, dates, redirects, headers and messages in a HTTP context (both incoming and outgoing). It also provides means for client negotiation of preferred language and charset, as well as a convenient way to exchange arbitrary data with caching and resuming capabilities.
>
> Also provided is a powerful request and parallel interface (PHP5+), if the extension is built with cURL support.

In addition, most PHP functions able to work with remote resources can be used with custom [Stream Contexts](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php), which will allow you to [configure how PHP connects to resources.](http://de.php.net/manual/en/context.php)

Comment: This is a wonderful extension, I've used it extensively and strongly prefer it to cURL. (yes, I know PECL HTTP uses some cURL under the hood)

Comment: +1 Probably the best option. But I've also read it uses cURL as backend in any case (just with more sensible defaults).

Answer (score 3):

I typically use [`Zend_Http_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) unless im working in a Symfony project - in that case i use `sfWebBrowserPlugin`.